# calling functions from command prompt

Tags: python

Here is the extract of the script (untested)

```
def start_custer():
    try:
        myidentifier=mydict['DescribeClustersResponse']['DescribeClustersResult']['Clusters'][0]['ClusterIdentifier']
    except IndexError:
        conn.restore_from_cluster_snapshot('vi-mar5-deliveryreport-new', mysnapidentifier, availability_zone='us-east-1a')

def stop_cluster():
    try:    
        myidentifier=mydict['DescribeClustersResponse']['DescribeClustersResult']['Clusters'][0]['ClusterIdentifier']
        conn.delete_cluster(myidentifier, skip_final_cluster_snapshot=False, final_cluster_snapshot_identifier=myvar)
    except:
        print "error"
```

1. Are these functions technically (syntactically) correct?
2. How do I call them while calling the python script? I need to either start or stop cluster at a time, not both.

Comment: Well, you need to catch both `KeyError` and `IndexError`.

Comment: May I suggest that you test it yourself?

Comment: That depends on the variables used. But yeah, seems like it's *syntatically* correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your second question, I'd parse the command line via [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Manage the cluster")
parser.add_argument("action", choices=["stop", "start"],
                    help="Action to perform")

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.action == "start":
    start_cluster()
if args.action == "stop":
    stop_cluster()
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have shown you the best way to do this, but for the record, you can also do this from the command line:

```
python -c "import cluster; cluster.start_cluster()"
```

(assuming your module file is named `cluster.py` -- adjust the `import` statement accordingly if not)

This isn't as user-friendly as parsing the command line yourself but it'll do in a pinch.

Answer (score 1):

1) It's `Syntactically` correct, if you have defined `conn` somewhere and imported it !

2)

```
def stop_cluster():
    ## Your code

def fun():
    ## your code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    globals()[sys.argv[1]]()
```

Usage:

```
   python2.7 test_syn.py fun
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added a main function to your script which checks for command line args, then prompts you if no valid argument has been supplied:

```
import sys

def start_custer():
    try:
        myidentifier=mydict['DescribeClustersResponse']['DescribeClustersResult']['Clusters'][0]['ClusterIdentifier']
    except IndexError:
        conn.restore_from_cluster_snapshot('vi-mar5-deliveryreport-new', mysnapidentifier, availability_zone='us-east-1a')

def stop_cluster():
    try:    
        myidentifier=mydict['DescribeClustersResponse']['DescribeClustersResult']['Clusters'][0]['ClusterIdentifier']
        conn.delete_cluster(myidentifier, skip_final_cluster_snapshot=False, final_cluster_snapshot_identifier=myvar)
    except:
        print "error"

def main():
    valid_args, proc = ['start','stop'], None

    # check if cmd line args were passed in (>1 as sys.argv[0] is name of program)
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        if sys.argv[1].lower() in valid_args:
            proc = sys.argv[1].lower()

    # if a valid arg was passed in this has been stored in proc, if not prompt user
    while not proc or proc not in valid_args:
        print "\nPlease state which procedure you want to call, valid options are:", valid_args
        proc = raw_input('>>> ').lower()

        # prompt user if invalid
        if proc not in valid_args:
            print proc, 'is not a valid selection.'

    if proc == 'start':
        start_custer()
    elif proc == 'stop':
        stop_cluster()

# this makes the script automatically call main when starting up
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can call this from the command line e.g. if you were in the same directory as the file (e.g. named cluster_ctrl.py) just:

```
python cluster_ctrl.py start
```

Comment: If I use anything other than start or stop, I get the message. But why do I get the python prompt? like >>>

Comment: If you look at the script, the prompt is actually in there in a `raw_input` call. It's not the real Python prompt.

Comment: @shantanuo as kindall said, this isn't the actual python prompt, it is just the text that I happened to use inside the raw_input function. Feel free to ask if you have any otrher questions about the code.